# How to exclude recurring regions in plot function?

Tags: plotting

The quest is simple: I want to plot $y=\log x$ over range $\{0,100\}$, while exluding all $\{\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}+\delta\}$ regions for integer n.

I know `RegionFunction` might do the trick but I just can't devise the code.

Answer (score 4):

assemble a bunch of separate plots:

```
 del = 1/10
 max = Floor[(1 + del^2 )/2/del]
 reg = Partition[Join[{del},
 Flatten[{#, # + del} & /@ Table[ Sqrt[i], {i, max^2}]]], 2];
```

> {{1/10, 1}, {11/10, Sqrt[2]}, {1/10 + Sqrt[2], Sqrt[
>     3]}, {1/10 + Sqrt[3], 2}, {21/10, Sqrt[5]}, {1/10 + Sqrt[5], Sqrt[6]
>     }...

```
Show[{Plot[Log[x], {x, #[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ reg}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

notice the curve has to end at 5 for del=1/10 since `5+del > Sqrt[26]` and so everything after is excluded.

Answer (score 3):

```
δ = .1;
mymask[x_, δ_] = 
  Sum[UnitBox[(x - Sqrt[n])/δ], {n, 1, 100, 4}];
Plot[
 (1 - mymask[x, δ]) Log[x] , 
 {x, 1, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

It gets compressed when you plot all the way to $x \to 100$ or use every value of $\sqrt{n}$, but this should allow you to tailor your graph as needed.

Comment: If you're willing to tolerate some messages you can use `Log[x] / (1 - mymask[x, \[Delta]])` and set `ExclusionsStyle -> None`.

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

As george2079 rightly points out the problem comes because `Sqrt[n]-Sqrt[n-1]` is sometimes smaller than `\[Delta]`. This works, instead:

```
\[Delta] = .8;
region =
  Interval @@ 
   Table[N@{Sqrt[n - 1] + (Sqrt[n] - Sqrt[n - 1])*\[Delta], 
      Sqrt[n]}, {n, 1, 10^2}];

Plot[Log10[x], x \[Element] region]
```

[image: update]

### Original

Here's a sort-of "non-answer" that one would expect to work based on the `Plot` docs:

```
\[Delta] = .1;
region =
  Interval @@ Table[N@{Sqrt[n - 1] + \[Delta], Sqrt[n]}, {n, 1, 10^2}];

Plot[Log10[x], x \[Element] region]
```

[image]

Clearly something goes sideways. Of course this is better than my first attempt which involved taking the complement of `Interval[{0,10}]` and `Interval @@ Table[N@{Sqrt[n], Sqrt[n] + \[Delta]}, {n, 1, 10^2}]`. Crashed my kernel.

Also note that `RegionFunction` doesn't work all that well because it seems to apply after the points are sampled and resampling doesn't occur around it. Gives odd exclusions and whatnot.

Comment: the problem occurs where `Sqrt[n - 1] + \[Delta] > Sqrt[n]`

Comment: @george2079 right you are. Updated the answer to deal with that.